# Does derived class inherits v pointer from base class and uses that only or it have its own v pointer also?

Tags: c++

Does derived class inherits v pointer from base class and uses that only or it have its own v pointer also?

In inheritance hierarchy, does derived has it own v pointer or it uses inherited v pointer from base class and when we create object of derived class so compiler uses that inherited v pointer to point to derived class virtual table?

Comment: Its a vptr @user12238659

Comment: Every class with virtual methods (or derived from a class with virtual methods) has its own vtable pointer. Otherwise, RTTI (run-time type identification) wouldn't work. Though, the vtable of a derived class may contain pointers pointing to base class functions if they haven't been overridden. Or, do you ask how many vtable pointers there are in a derived class (concerning memory layout)?

Comment: virtual tables is an implementation detail. If you want to understand how virtual dispatch works you do not necessarily need to know a bit about virtual tables

Comment: FYI: [Virtual method table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)

Answer (score 0):

There is only one vptr per object, and it points to the desired vtable during run-time.